# How to Fix an Old Door Frame that is not Square or Plumb

Tags: doors, hinges

My house is 100 years old and while trying to install a new storm door I found the door frame is not square or plumb.  Is there any easy fix for this besides tearing apart all the original wood trim?

Comment: Probably not, but trim should be able to be removed carefully.  Depending on how bad it it is, maybe if lucky, some well placed long screws might be enough to pull it back in place.

Comment: `easy` is a generic therm, what is easy for me might be difficult for you or vice versa. So the question is how experienced are you in framing work ?

Comment: I've never done framing work but I am a beginner woodworker and I do have quite a few tools.  I'm definitely comfortable learning how to do it myself and do it properly.

Comment: OK, then first measure and report the vertical and horizontal measured with leveler, also use the `@Ruskes` so I get alerted to your comments.

Comment: @Ruskes Thanks so much for helping me with this.  I hate to ask this but what do you mean by vertical and horizontal measured with leveler?  How exactly do I measure?

Comment: OK, do you have a leveler ? if so, use it to determine how much adjustment is needed .

Comment: like this one `CRAFTSMAN Torpedo Level, 9-Inch (CMHT82390)`

Comment: hold the leveler on to the frame then lift one side to see how much is it out of level

Comment: read the how to here: https://homeguides.sfgate.com/level-door-frame-28879.html

Comment: You should start with a picture of the door in the door jamb.  Which dimensions are out of plumb square?  Is the door sitting in the jamb properly?  You should have a 5' level ideally to tell how far out of plumb each side of the jamb is.  you'll need a smaller level 24" to tell how out of level the head of the door jamb is.